# Need to Center a div take position absolute

Tags: html, css

I need to center my div `#banner`, but its taking `position:absolute`. Sometimes I make it with jQuery but now I need to make it with CSS. Any help please.

[Here's the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6yJ7U/)

Comment: Which div needs to be centered, and what have you tried?

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: please always try to include some relevant code to your question too instead of just pointing at jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to horizontally center an absolutely positioned div that has a fixed width do this:

```
div {
    position:absolute;
    margin:0 auto;
    left:0; right:0;
}
```

In your case:
**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6yJ7U/1/)** (The pink is the #banner)

```
#banner {
    width: 996px;
    height: 150px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1000;
    margin:0 auto;
    left:0;right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  /* give container a size depending on viewport */
  width: 80vw; height: 90vh;
  background: grey /* so we can see its area */
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  /* put top corner of .box element border-box 
   * at 50% of .container height from 
   * the top edge of .container padding-box and 
   * at 50% of .container width from 
   * the left edge of .container padding-box */
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  padding: calc(3em + 3vmin + 3vmax);
  /* move .box 
   * by 50% of its own border-box width 
   * in the negative (leftwards) direction of the x axis and
   * by 50% of its own border-box height 
   * in the negative (upwards) direction of the y axis */
  translate: -50% -50%;
  background: crimson /* so we can see its area */
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='box'></div>
</div>
```

```
.container{
 position:relative; 
 width:100vw;
 height:100vh;
}

.box{
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
}
```